# How to use import Android-PullToRefresh

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, pull-to-refresh

https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

From this link url
I using android studio and i want to import library to my project, other library has dependencies it's easy to use like

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.xxxxxx
}
```

But this library has not, How can i import this library to my project Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need that project, get Android support library and try this tutorial:
http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
compile group: 'com.github.chrisbanes.pulltorefresh', name: 'parent', version: '2.1.1'
```

found here:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.chrisbanes.pulltorefresh/parent/2.1.1

or use this library derived from this one:

https://github.com/naver/android-pull-to-refresh/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide